# Problema al ejecutar una query con JDBC en Oracle desde Java

Tags: java, oracle, sql, jdbc

**RESUELTO**

chicos:

Llevo toda la mañana buscando soluciones a este problema y no he encontrado ninguna. Veréis, necesito ejecutar un INSERT en una BD Oracle 12c desde un programa en Java, estoy usando el jdbc7 y el JDK 1.8. La BD conecta bien, pero cuando llega la hora de ejecutar el executeUpdate() me lanza una excepción.

El código de mi programa es este:

```
public static void escribirLogBD(String mensaje, String nombrePCOrigen, String errorSource, int errorCode){
    try {
        Connection con = conectarBD();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO "+tablaDB+" (TIMESTAMP, ERRORSOURCE, ERRORCODE, ERRORDESC, SERVER) VALUES (SYSDATE, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
        PreparedStatement pst;
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, errorSource);
        pst.setInt(2, errorCode);
        pst.setString(3, mensaje);
        pst.setString(4, nombrePCOrigen);
        pst.executeUpdate();
        pst.close();
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        escribirLog(rutaLogs, "Error en la base de datos. Detalles: "+ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Y la excepción es la siguiente:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: comando SQL no terminado correctamente

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4875)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1361)
at xonefilecopyservice.FileCopyService.escribirLogBD(FileCopyService.java:249)
at xonefilecopyservice.FileCopyService.main(FileCopyService.java:115)
```

Cualquier ayuda será de agradecer.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Creo que el problema es el `;` que tienes al final de la sentencia sql. Prueba sin él.

Comment: Madre mía!!! Eso mismo era!! Muchísimas gracias!!

Comment: Demasiadas horas viendo esos errores :-D